# Setting Up Port Forwarding For Foscam Camera With Apple Airport Extreme

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I am trying to setup a Foscam FI8189W IP Camera to work with my Airport wifi network. I have tried to follow the instructions that Foscam has given but I believe the problem is with my Airport setup.

So to give you an idea of what sort of a setup I am running, I have a 5th gen Airport Extreme and a 5th gen Airport Express. Both are connected to my Comcast modem/router through a gigabit switcher and the Express just extends the Extreme.

As per the Foscam instructions here: http://youtu.be/8VyKJgCFOZ8 I get to the point of going to the Network tab of my Airport Extreme and turning on DHCP and NAT and then clicking the + in the Port Settings section. Here is my issue, the DHCP range only allows me to go from 10.0.1.2 to 10.0.1.200 and my camera's ip address is 10.0.0...

If I try to change my camera IP address manually to a 10.0.1... number than it says that is invalid and if I try to change the DHCP range it says it will conflict.

Any ideas???

Comment: Is the Comcast modem providing DHCP as well?

Comment: @patrix How can I check that?

Comment: The fact that you had to turn DHCP on on the Extreme already gives a clue, but you would need to look at the configuration of the Comcast modem.

Comment: @patrix I logged in to my Comcast modem and it appears that it IS providing DHCP. Does that mean that I can setup port forwarding on that and have it be compatible with my Airport setup?

Comment: All I can say is that you shouldn't run DHCP on the Extreme as well (because this will probably conflict with the Comcast). Port forwarding is a different matter, but I hope that people more knowledgeable to network configurations will be able to provide an answer here.

Comment: @patrix You were right, this was the issue. I setup port forwarding on my Comcast modem/router and now it's working great. Thanks!